# ERROR: Can't use --version w/ multiple gems. Use name:ver instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm when i run passenger-install-nginx-module, i get this message:

```
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:

  rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvm repair all
```

however when i ran this command i got this:

```
ERROR:  Can't use --version w/ multiple gems. Use name:ver instead.
```

just wondering how to get round this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your .gemrc file has wrong options.

For example, no-ri has two dashes in the beginning.

```
gem: -–no-ri -–no-rdoc
```